# Converting Java Code from working with Ints to Strings

Tags: java

I have been changing my code from ints to strings. I have converted everything but two lines that I am stumped on I knowvI should be able to use compareTo to get it to work but I am not understanding how to change

```
if(key<insNode.getKey()){
```

Any tips on how I can do this? Or is compareTo the best way to change this?

```
     public class BSTcode {

            public class Node {

                private Node left;
            private Node right;
            private String key;

            public Node(String key){
                this.key = key;
                left = null;
                right = null;
            }

            public void setLeftLeaf(Node left){
                this.left = left;
            }

            public void setRightLeaf(Node right){
                this.right = right;
            }

            public Node getLeftLeaf(){
                return left;
            }
            public Node getRightLeaf(){
                return right;
            }
            public void setKey(String k){
                this.key = k;
            }
            public String getKey(){
                return key;
            }
            public void print(){
                System.out.println("The number is "+ getKey());
            }
        }

        Node root;
        public Node getRoot(){

            return root;
        }

        public BSTcode(){
            root = null;
        }

        public void insert (String key){
             Node n1 = new Node(key);

             if(root == null){
                 root = n1;
             }
             else{
                 Node parIns = root;
                 Node insNode = root;

                 while(insNode!= null){
                     parIns = insNode;

                     if(key<insNode.getKey()){
                         insNode =insNode.getLeftLeaf();

                     }
                     else{
                         insNode = insNode.getRightLeaf();
                     }

                 }
                 if(key<parIns.getKey()){
                     parIns.setLeftLeaf(n1);
                 }
                 else{
                     parIns.setRightLeaf(n1);
                 }
             }

                 }
                 public void printInorder(Node n){

                     if(n!= null){
                         printInorder(n.getLeftLeaf());
                         n.print();
                         printInorder(n.getRightLeaf());
             }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, you should use `compareTo`. Did you read the documentation for `compareTo`? Was there some part of it you didn't understand? If you could give more details about your confusion, we'll be better able to help you

Comment: I have looked at some documentation on it, but I am not getting the whole concept. I know compareTo is to compare two strings. Do you know any good sites to read up on it?

Comment: Well, the documentation. You call `compareTo(x, y)` and it returns a negative number if `x` is "earlier than" `y`, a positive number if `x` is "later than" `y`, and 0 if they're sorted equally. So `"abc".compareTo("banana")` will return a negative value, for example.

Comment: When you say earlier and later you mean on a scale of abc's where a is the earliest and z is the latest?

Comment: Yes. Dictionary ordering, basically - except that `compareTo` uses the ordering of the Unicode code points, so all capital letters are deemed earlier than all lower-case letters, for example. There are other ways to perform a case-insensitive or culture-sensitive comparison, but stick to the basics to start with.

Comment: Ok thanks I'm going to try changing that code to see if it works or give errors. I'll comment in a bit if I have other questions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95006/discussion-between-shema-martin-and-jon-skeet).